# Что означает FormProcessQueue().PanelBase

Tags: java, swing

```
frame.setContentPane(new FormProcessQueue().PanelBase);
```

Запись `FormProcessQueue().PanelBase` мне как-то не понятна...

```
public class FormProcessQueue {
    private JPanel PanelBase;
    private JTextArea queue1;
    private JTextArea queue2;

    public static void main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Очередь");
        frame.setContentPane(new FormProcessQueue().PanelBase);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
...
```

Comment: @Letfar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

[[@Letfar](/users/29333/letfar)](/users/29333/letfar) Это обращение к полю `PanelBase` анонимного объекта `new FormProcessQueue()`. Все равно что ты напишешь вот так. И кстати, пиши названия полей с маленькой буквы. Не C# же.

```
private JPanel panelBase;
private JTextArea queue1;
private JTextArea queue2;

public static void main() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Очередь");
    FormProcessQueue form=new FormProcessQueue();
    frame.setContentPane(form.panelBase);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @argamidon: ИМНИП в C# с большой буквы принято писать только названия публичных полей (если они, не дай бог, есть) и свойств.